# Better way to load schedule without any delay using JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have an application that shows a schedule per week. All the appointments are stored as database entries. I use a class (`ScheduleCells`) to manage these entries and store them in a bean (`ScheduleCellbean`) and return an two dimensional ArrayList. In my `index.jsp` I have the following code to retrieve this ArrayList and fill in the schedule. In the `index.jsp` I send a request to a servlet.

Index.jsp:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    fillSchedule = function (w) {

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "schedule?w=" + w);
        xhr.send();

        <%
            int i;
            int j;
            int w = 0;

            if (session.getAttribute("w") != null) {
               w = (Integer) session.getAttribute("w");
            }

            ScheduleCells sc = new ScheduleCells();

             for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {

                 for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {

                     ScheduleCellBean cell = sc.getCellByHDW(i + 1, j + 1, w);

                         if (cell.getExists()) {
        %>

        createNewAppointment(<%= j%>, <%= i%>,
            "<%= cell.getSubject_scheduled_subjectabbr()%>",
            "<%= cell.getUser_scheduled_userabbr()%>",
            "<%= cell.getScheduled_groupname()%>");

        <% }}}%>

    };

    fillSchedule(7);

</script>
```

ScheduleCellbean:

```
public class ScheduleCellBean extends ScheduleCells {

    private boolean exists = false; 
    private String scheduled_id;
    private String scheduled_date;
    private String scheduled_hour;
    private String user_scheduled_firstname;
    private String user_scheduled_lastname;
    private String user_scheduled_username;
    private String user_scheduled_password;
    private String user_scheduled_userabbr;
    private String user_scheduled_subjectname;
    private String user_scheduled_subjectabbr;
    private String scheduled_groupname;
    private String subject_scheduled_subjectname;
    private String subject_scheduled_subjectabbr;
    private String scheduled_datetimerequest;
    private String user_request_firstname;
    private String user_request_lastname;
    private String user_request_username;
    private String user_request_password;
    private String user_request_userabbr;
    private String user_request_subjectname;
    private String user_request_subjectabbr;

    //Getters And Setters.

}
```

ScheduleCellServlet.jsp:

```
@WebServlet(name = "ScheduleCell", urlPatterns = {"/schedule"})
public class ScheduleCellServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("w", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("w")));

     }

    //Default HTTP Servlet functions.

}
```

Everything works just fine, but because I'm working with a servlet there's a delay, which results in that the schedule seems to fail to load, but on a refresh the session attrribute comes through and the right schedule is loaded. So any changes I make (e.g. `fillSchedule(8)`) only take place when I reload the page. But I like the schedule to be interactive, meaning that an user can choose a week and the right schedule of that week immedately pops up. The schedule that I see lacks behind on what I've chosen, when I refrech the page my chosen schedule is visible, but at the same moment the schedule of week 7 is being loaded again, but again only visible when I refesh the page.

My question is: How can I achieve this in such a way that I don't (manually) have to refresh the page?

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: use ajax to call get data without refreshing page asynchronously.

Comment: Could you give me an example or a proper reference, as I have never worked with AJAX before?

Comment: use http://mycodingtricks.com/jquery/jquery-auto-load-and-refresh-div-on-ajax-call-without-reloading-page/ url for reference.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, I'll try to implement it later, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Auto refresh your jsp page for fresh response.

code snippet:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Refresh Header Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>Auto Refresh Header Example</h2>
<%
   // Set refresh, autoload time as 5 seconds
   response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 5);
   // Get current time
   Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
   String am_pm;
   int hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR);
   int minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
   int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
   if(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0)
      am_pm = "AM";
   else
      am_pm = "PM";
   String CT = hour+":"+ minute +":"+ second +" "+ am_pm;
   out.println("Crrent Time: " + CT + "\n");
%>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example works fine, but I cannot implement this, as refreshing the page changes the current week back to 7 again, refreshing on a interval makes the browser slow and all the new requests to the server causes strain, too.